# Vim switch to previous buffer from within tmux

Tags: tmux

The default key binding for switching to previous buffer in Vim is <kbd>CTRL-6</kbd> but this does not work from within tmux.

My tmux prefix is <kbd>CTRL-a</kbd> if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 key mappings for editing alternate file. `CTRL-6` and `CTRL-^`

Try pressing `Ctrl+Shift+6`(which is `CTRL-^`)